# Bind collection of an enumeration to checkboxes

Tags: silverlight

I've did some google but didn't found out an answer...

Is there some way to bind a collection of a given enum type to a group of checkboxes, with the possibility of having multiple of them selected?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I'm intending to use two-way binding.